# copying one row to another excel spreadsheet after meeting a value using VBA

Tags: vba

so i'm a novice at excel visual basic but i looked up a code and for some reason i keep getting an error can anyone help to solve this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Repairs As Worksheet    
Dim void2 As Worksheet    
Dim Engineer As String    
Dim finalrow As Integer    

Set Sheet1 = Repairs    
Set sheet4 = void2

Set Engineer = void2.Range("b2").Value

void2.Range("A7:AI4000").ClearContents

Repairs.Select    
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    

For i = 7 To finalrow    
     If Cells(i, 10) = voids Then    
         Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 34)).Copy    
         void2.Select    
         Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecialxlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats    
        Repairs.Select    
    End If    
Next i

void2.Select    
Range("b2").Select    


End Sub
```

the Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() is highlighted in yellow after i click the run it comes up with an error stating -compile error: invalid use of property. 
All i'm trying to do is in worksheet "void 2" click on a drop down list select the criteria such as VOID or ADAM or JIM etc, and then click a button to scan all the data in column L of repairs (this is where the original data is) and pick out that particular row of data and copy it onto "void 2" sheet.

please help i would appreciate all the help i can get! thank you.

Comment: you have your sets backwards.  `Set Repairs = Sheet1`

Comment: Please [edit] your question title so that it's helpful to other people that would be having the same problem as you - what would you type in Google?

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, i have tried changing it but i still get the same error and  Private sub commandbutton1_Click() gets highlighted yellow and Set Engineer gets highlighted blue with the same error message.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Repairs As Worksheet
Dim void2 As Worksheet
Dim Engineer As String
Dim finalrow As Integer


Set Repairs = Sheet1
Set void2 = Sheet2
Set Engineer = void2.Range("b2").Value
void2.Range("A7:AI4000").ClearContents
Repairs.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 7 To finalrow
If Cells(i, 10) = voids Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 34)).Copy
void2.Select
Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
Repairs.Select
End If
Next i
void2.Select
Range("b2").Select
End Sub